# What does `Row-level security and object-level security cannot be combined from different roles` mean?

Tags: powerbi

I understand that for RLS you can define roles, each role has a filter criteria on table, and then publish the dataset, and in the service we can add users into the roles.

I am learning about OLS, and understand that for each role I can set None/Read permission on table.

> Row-level security and object-level security cannot be combined from
> different roles because it could introduce unintended access to
> secured data.

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/tabular-models/object-level-security?view=asallproducts-allversions#restrictions

What does `Row-level security and object-level security cannot be combined from different roles` mean?